# SendKeys in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi

Hi I'm trying to do the classic `SendKeys ('hello world');` was done in visual basic delphi but I discovered that you can not do that.

Does anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the Win32 API [`keybd_event()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SendInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.  Both functions are declared in Delphi's `Windows` unit.

For example:

```
uses
  Windows;

procedure SendKeys(const S: String);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin
    // keybd_event() does not support Unicode, so you should use SendInput() instead...
    keybd_event(S[I], MapVirtualKey(S[I], 0),0, 0);
    keybd_event(S[I], MapVirtualKey(S[I], 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  end;
end;
```

```
uses
  Windows;

{$POINTERMATH ON}
procedure SendKeys(const S: String);
var
  InputEvents: PInput;
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  if S = '' then Exit;
  GetMem(InputEvents, SizeOf(TInput) * (Length(S) * 2));
  try
    J := 0;
    for I := 1 to Length(S) do
    begin
      InputEvents[J].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
      InputEvents[J].ki.wVk := 0;
      InputEvents[J].ki.wScan := Ord(S[I]);
      InputEvents[J].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
      InputEvents[J].ki.time := 0;
      InputEvents[J].ki.dwExtraInfo := 0;
      Inc(J);
      InputEvents[J].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
      InputEvents[J].ki.wVk := 0;
      InputEvents[J].ki.wScan := Ord(S[I]);
      InputEvents[J].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_UNICODE or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
      InputEvents[J].ki.time := 0;
      InputEvents[J].ki.dwExtraInfo := 0;
      Inc(J);
    end;
    SendInput(J, InputEvents[0], SizeOf(TInput));
  finally
    FreeMem(InputEvents);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Remy , but the second code throws me this error: [DCC Error] stub.pas(208): E2016 Array type required. I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you see my edit with the `{$POINTERMATH ON}` directive added?

Comment: sorry, no I noticed that detail.

the code now it says this: [DCC Error] test.pas (213): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Word' and 'Char'

Comment: seems that today is not my lucky day : [DCC Error] test.pas(216): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'time' [DCC Error] test.pas(217): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'dwExtraInfo' [DCC Error] test.pas(223): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'time' [DCC Error] test.pas(224): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'dwExtraInfo'

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the functions I've assembled to use in some automation projects I had to do in past. They utilize `keybd_event()` API.

```
procedure SendKeys(const AString: String; const AAmount: Integer = 1);
const
  TReadableChars = [32..126];
  TShiftChars    = [33..43, 58, 60, 62..90, 94..95, 123..126];
type
  TKeyInfo = record
               AsChar  : Char;
               AsOrd   : Integer;
               VK      : Integer;
               SC      : Integer;
               UseShift: Boolean;
             end;
  TKeys    = TList<TKeyInfo>;
var
  key   : TKeyInfo;
  keys  : TKeys;
  C1, C2: Integer;
begin
  keys := TKeys.Create;
  try
    for C1 := 1 to Length(AString) do
    begin
      key.AsChar := AString[C1];
      key.AsOrd := Ord(key.AsChar);

      if key.AsOrd in TReadableChars then
      begin
        key.VK := VkKeyScan(key.AsChar);
        key.UseShift := key.AsOrd in TShiftChars;
        key.SC := MapVirtualKey(key.VK, 0);
        keys.Add(key);
      end;
    end;

    for C1 := 1 to AAmount do
      for C2 := 0 to keys.Count - 1 do
      begin
        key := keys[C2];

        if key.UseShift then
          keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0);

        keybd_event(key.VK, key.SC, 0, 0);
        keybd_event(key.VK, key.SC, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

        if key.UseShift then
          keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
      end;
  finally
    keys.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure SendKey(const AVKCode: Integer; const AAmount: Integer = 1);
var
  C1: Integer;
begin
  for C1 := 1 to AAmount do
  begin
    keybd_event(AVKCode, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(AVKCode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is also capable to **send special chars** like Enter/Chr(13), Escape/Chr(27), ...

```
procedure SendKeyString(Text: String);
var
    i: Integer;
    Shift: Boolean;
    vk, ScanCode: Word;
    ch: Char;
    c, s: Byte;
const
    vk_keys: Array[0..9] of Byte =
        (VK_HOME, VK_END, VK_UP, VK_DOWN, VK_LEFT,
        VK_RIGHT, VK_PRIOR, VK_NEXT, VK_INSERT, VK_DELETE);
    vk_shft: Array[0..2] of Byte = (VK_SHIFT, VK_CONTROL, VK_MENU);
    flags: Array[False..True] of Integer = (KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
begin
    Shift := False;
    for i := 1 to Length(Text) do
    begin
        ch := Text[i];
        if ch >= #250 then
        begin
            s := Ord(ch) - 250;
            Shift := not Odd(s);
            c := vk_shft[s shr 1];
            ScanCode := MapVirtualKey(c,0);
            Keybd_Event(c, Scancode, Flags[shift], 0);
        end
        else
        begin
            vk := 0;
            if ch >= #240 then
                c := vk_keys[Ord(ch) - 240]
            else
                if ch >= #228 then {228 (F1) => $70 (vk_F1)}
                    c := Ord(ch) - 116
                else
                    if ch < #110 then
                        c := Ord(ch)
                    else
                    begin
                        vk := VkKeyScan(ch);
                        c := LoByte(vk);
                    end;
            ScanCode := MapVirtualKey(c,0);
            if not Shift and (Hi(vk) > 0) then { $2A = scancode of VK_SHIFT }
                Keybd_Event(VK_SHIFT, $2A, 0, 0);
            Keybd_Event(c,scancode, 0, 0);
            Keybd_Event(c,scancode, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            if not Shift and (Hi(vk) > 0) then
                Keybd_Event(VK_SHIFT, $2A, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

And here the whole unit (containing `SendKeyString()`) in context:

```
{****************************************************}
{              SendKeys Unit for Delphi 32           }
{    Copyright (c) 1999 by Borut Batagelj (Slovenia) }
{                       Aleksey Kuznetsov (Ukraine)  }
{            Home Page: www.utilmind.com             }
{            E-Mail: info@utilmind.com               }
{****************************************************}

unit SendKeys;

interface

uses
    Windows, SysUtils;

const
    SK_BKSP = #8;
    SK_TAB = #9;
    SK_ENTER = #13;
    SK_ESC = #27;
    SK_ADD = #107;
    SK_SUB = #109;
    SK_F1 = #228;
    SK_F2 = #229;
    SK_F3 = #230;
    SK_F4 = #231;
    SK_F5 = #232;
    SK_F6 = #233;
    SK_F7 = #234;
    SK_F8 = #235;
    SK_F9 = #236;
    SK_F10 = #237;
    SK_F11 = #238;
    SK_F12 = #239;
    SK_HOME = #240;
    SK_END = #241;
    SK_UP = #242;
    SK_DOWN = #243;
    SK_LEFT = #244;
    SK_RIGHT = #245;
    SK_PGUP = #246;
    SK_PGDN = #247;
    SK_INS = #248;
    SK_DEL = #249;
    SK_SHIFT_DN = #250;
    SK_SHIFT_UP = #251;
    SK_CTRL_DN = #252;
    SK_CTRL_UP = #253;
    SK_ALT_DN = #254;
    SK_ALT_UP = #255;

procedure SendKeyString(Text: String);
procedure SendKeysToTitle(WindowTitle: String; Text: String);
procedure SendKeysToHandle(WindowHandle: hWnd; Text: String);
procedure MakeWindowActive(wHandle: hWnd);
function GetHandleFromWindowTitle(TitleText: String): hWnd;

implementation

procedure SendKeyString(Text: String);
var
    i: Integer;
    Shift: Boolean;
    vk, ScanCode: Word;
    ch: Char;
    c, s: Byte;
const
    vk_keys: Array[0..9] of Byte =
        (VK_HOME, VK_END, VK_UP, VK_DOWN, VK_LEFT,
        VK_RIGHT, VK_PRIOR, VK_NEXT, VK_INSERT, VK_DELETE);
    vk_shft: Array[0..2] of Byte = (VK_SHIFT, VK_CONTROL, VK_MENU);
    flags: Array[False..True] of Integer = (KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
begin
    Shift := False;
    for i := 1 to Length(Text) do
    begin
        ch := Text[i];
        if ch >= #250 then
        begin
            s := Ord(ch) - 250;
            Shift := not Odd(s);
            c := vk_shft[s shr 1];
            ScanCode := MapVirtualKey(c,0);
            Keybd_Event(c, Scancode, Flags[shift], 0);
        end
        else
        begin
            vk := 0;
            if ch >= #240 then
                c := vk_keys[Ord(ch) - 240]
            else
                if ch >= #228 then {228 (F1) => $70 (vk_F1)}
                    c := Ord(ch) - 116
                else
                    if ch < #110 then
                        c := Ord(ch)
                    else
                    begin
                        vk := VkKeyScan(ch);
                        c := LoByte(vk);
                    end;
            ScanCode := MapVirtualKey(c,0);
            if not Shift and (Hi(vk) > 0) then { $2A = scancode of VK_SHIFT }
                Keybd_Event(VK_SHIFT, $2A, 0, 0);
            Keybd_Event(c,scancode, 0, 0);
            Keybd_Event(c,scancode, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            if not Shift and (Hi(vk) > 0) then
                Keybd_Event(VK_SHIFT, $2A, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure MakeWindowActive(wHandle: hWnd);
begin
    if IsIconic(wHandle) then
        ShowWindow(wHandle, SW_RESTORE)
    else
        BringWindowToTop(wHandle);
end;

function GetHandleFromWindowTitle(TitleText: String): hWnd;
var
    StrBuf: Array[0..$FF] of Char;
begin
    Result := FindWindow(PChar(0), StrPCopy(StrBuf, TitleText));
end;

procedure SendKeysToTitle(WindowTitle: String; Text: String);
var
    Window: hWnd;
begin
    Window := GetHandleFromWindowTitle(WindowTitle);
    MakeWindowActive(Window);
    SendKeyString(Text);
end;

procedure SendKeysToHandle(WindowHandle: hWnd; Text: String);
begin
    MakeWindowActive(WindowHandle);
    SendKeyString(Text);
end;

end.
```