# How to send virtual keys to other application using delphi

Tags: delphi

I need to send several virtual keys (VK_RETURN) from my delphi application (myapp.exe) into another application such as (notepade).

The OS that I use are Windows 10 64 bit.

I read : How to send an "ENTER" key press to another application? , Delphi XE - Send Ctrl+Key to 3rd Party Application (did not work for me) and other previous asked question. But still I'm getting confused.

How to set the focus to the target application ?

How to send the virtual keys to the targeted application ?

Simple example : I want to send password into another program at runtime from my delphi application. How to do that ?

PS : I tried PostMessage() and SendMessage().

Comment: You want to automate typing a password into Notepad? I don't think that Notepad ever asks for passwords. Do bear in mind that different programs accept input in different ways. It's entirely plausible that the program that you actually target does not want you to hack it in this way. The identity and implementation of the program that you target matters. Normally though, when you want to automate another app, you would use the platform automation libraries rather than naive input faking.

Comment: I have encrypted same data with this software and it's working fine.

Comment: now i need to lunch that software from Delphi and input my password automate

Comment: you would use the platform automation libraries.

Comment: Can you give me a topic about that?

Comment: Not *ole automation*, but **UI Automation**. Please don't ask us to do web search for you. FWIW, there are literally thousands of posts on this site from people trying to fake input when perhaps automation would be better. It's a complex topic that usually involves knowledge of the target app. Knowledge that only you have. That you won't share that knowledge makes it unlikely that you will get real detailed help.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using SendKeys - I have in the past.  But as David has said in comments to your post this is probably not the best way of going about it.

In any case, here is a link to a stack overflow question with some code examples that you might find useful.

[SendKeys in Delphi 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696107/sendkeys-in-delphi-2010)